# d3 | How can I preserve node.depth through flattening for force-directed links

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout, flatten

I'm working through Mike Bostock's collapsible force-directed graph: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1062288

One of the first actions within the update() function is to flatten() the nodes. I think this is done to make link generation easier.

When I run a tree layout on nodes normally, there is node.depth. (I want this to colour nodes according to level within hierarchy.) Running tree layout on flattened nodes, node.depth disappears. Unless, bizarrely, I run this line before var nodes = flatten(root):

```
var test = d3.layout.tree().nodes(root);
```

(i.e. here I am running a tree layout directly on the root array without first flattening it. If I do this, node.depth appears in the nodes array - but it doesn't survive update, e.g. user clicking to collapse.)

```
function flatten(root) {
  var nodes = [], i = 0;
  function recurse(node) {

    console.log(node.depth());//undefined

    if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
    if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
    nodes.push(node);
  }

  recurse(root);
  return nodes;
}
```

I can't access node.depth from within this function. Does anyone know how I can preserve node.depth?

full page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Force-Directed Graph</title>
<style>


    body { 
      color: #666; 
      background: white; 
      font: normal 14px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif; 
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    html, body {
        height: 100%;
    }


    div#network {
/*    background-color: aliceblue; */
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;

    }

    .node {
      cursor: pointer;
      stroke: dimgray;
      stroke-width: 0.5px;
    }



    .link {
      fill: none;
      stroke: lightgray;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }

    .hidden { 
      display: none; 
    }

    div.tooltip {
      color: #222; 
      background: #fff; 
      padding: .5em; 
      text-shadow: #f5f5f5 0 1px 0;
      border-radius: 2px; 
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px #a6a6a6; 
      opacity: 0.98; 
      position: absolute;
    }



</style>
<body>

    <div id="network"></div>

<script src="d3.v3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="graphics/variables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>


var containerObject = document.getElementById("network");
var containerWidth = containerObject.offsetWidth;
var containerHeight = containerObject.offsetHeight;


var width = containerWidth,
    height = containerHeight,
    root;

var scaleFactor = height/650;


var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .on("tick", tick);


var tooltip = d3.select("div#network").append("div").attr("class", "tooltip hidden");

var svg = d3.select("div#network").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

// svg.append("text").attr("x","0").attr("y","10").attr("text-anchor","start").attr("class","label").text(height);


var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.selectAll(".node");


d3.json("readme.json", function(error, json) {

  if (error) throw error;
  root = json;
  update();
});


function update() {

//  var test = d3.layout.tree().nodes(root);//mysteriously this maintains the depth
/*
    console.log('test');
    console.log(test);
*/

  var nodes = flatten(root),
      links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);


  // Restart the force layout.
   var chargeScale = d3.scale.linear().domain(d3.extent(nodes,function(d){ return d.size; })).range([(scaleFactor*-30),(-250*scaleFactor)]);

  force
      .nodes(nodes)
      .links(links)
      .gravity(0.1)
      .charge(function(d) { return scaleFactor*chargeScale(d.size) || (scaleFactor*-30); } )
      .linkDistance(scaleFactor*20)
      .friction(0.9)
      .start();

  // Update the links…
  link = link.data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Exit any old links.
  link.exit().remove();

  // Enter any new links.
  link.enter().insert("line", ".node")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });


  // Update the nodes…
  node = node.data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; }).attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d); });//colours(d.depth)

  // Exit any old nodes.
  node.exit().remove();

  // Enter any new nodes.
  node.enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
      .attr("r", function(d) { return scaleFactor*(Math.sqrt(d.size) / 12) || 4; })
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d); })
      .on("click", click)
      .call(force.drag);


    //Show/hide tooltip
    node

        .on("mousemove", function(d,i) {

            var msg = (d._children) ? "click to expand" : (d.children) ? "node name: " + d.name + "<br>[click to collapse]" : "node.name: " + d.name ;
            this.setAttribute("fill", "yellow");
            var mouse = d3.mouse(svg.node()).map( function(d) { return parseInt(d); } );
            tooltip.classed("hidden", false).attr("style", "left:"+(mouse[0]+25)+"px;top:"+mouse[1]+"px").html(msg)
        })
        .on("mouseout",  function(d,i) {
            this.setAttribute("fill", color(d))
            tooltip.classed("hidden", true)
        });      

}


function tick() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
  node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
}

// Color leaf nodes orange, and packages white or blue.
function color(d) {
  return d._children ? "red" : d.children ? "dodgerblue" : "lightblue";
}


// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (!d3.event.defaultPrevented) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d.children = null;
    } else {
      d.children = d._children;
      d._children = null;
    }
    update();
  }
}


// Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
function flatten(root) {
  var nodes = [], i = 0;
  function recurse(node) {

//        console.log(node.depth());

    if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
    if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
//     console.log(node.size);
    nodes.push(node);
  }
  recurse(root);
  return nodes;
}
</script>
```